# How do I display Latex in order to be read nicely?

Tags: mathjax

How do I display Latex in order to be read nicely?

Comment: Can you be more specific ?

Comment: If you are asking to see the source, you can right click on the generated Latex and choose "Show Source".

Comment: If you are asking how to make it display nicely, I had to download MathJax and it started working.

Comment: I know how to write in Latex but I don't know how to nicely display the text so that I am able to read it correctly. Thanks!

Comment: Where can I download MathJax safely? And how to install it? Thanks!

Comment: I just went to http://www.mathjax.org/ and clicked Download

Comment: Should this not be on http://tex.stackexchange.com/ rather than meta?

Comment: @Ross Millikan: I went here but I don't know what to do. http://www.mathjax.org/download/

Comment: All I did was download it and it worked.  Now it says I need to update the fonts for the latest version of Firefox and it won't do it.  But it seems to be working fine for me.  Sorry I can't help.

Comment: @RossMillikan - the download at mathjax.org/download is for SERVERS. Like kira I am confused on what an end user should do.